# Tag "swift3.0" should be removed

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

[swift3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3.0) is redundant to [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3).

A synonym wouldn't be useful until Swift 3.1, I suggest it just be deleted.

Comment: FWIW, there's already a [swift3.0] -> [swift3] synonym.

Comment: Oh wow, I somehow didn't notice that. Regardless, it should removed. There are only 2 questions tagged by it

Comment: 26 questions now.  You could always go through and manually remove the tag.

Comment: @JAL there's 26 now because trying to load `swift3.0` redirects to `swift3`

Comment: Is there any reason these tags don't have hyphens? We all know how important hyphens are, right?

Comment: This question title would have been better if it contained "swiftly".

Comment: One of the problem is that Swift 3 is not even in Beta right now. All of the posts that are currently tagged `swift3.0` or `swift3` should be actually tagged `swift-2.2` or just `swift`.

Comment: @Sulthan What does it matter if they call it "Beta" - it is out there in the wild now. You might as well tag them properly.